# Struts2 i18n - is it possible to easily see missing translations?

Tags: java, internationalization, struts2

I use struts2 property files to provide support for multiple languages and that works fine.

It is always very easy to forget some text hardcoded in some JSP or error not properly translated.

Is there an easy way to visualize this by replacing all the translated items by "ZZZ" for example, therefore we would only see the places where no translation is provided?

One idea would be to somehow dynamically (at runtime) replace all the text items in the properties file by "ZZZ" - is there an easy way to do that? I mean to override all translated items (without touching at the file itself, just in-memory)?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We simply create a property file with the value set to something like ?es_firstNameLabel, etc. and set the locale to use that property file. Then you look through your app for enlgish (or whatever your native language is). It's ugly, but that's good -- it's supposed to be ugly so that you stuff shows through more readily.

Unfortunately there's no real easy way to automate the checking part, you just need to regression your pages one by one.

When it's all said and done, you can go back and start replace the ?es_propertyLabel stuff with the appropriate values, so it works well as you start to create the new language entries.

Answer (score 0):

What you are referring to is a concept called pseudo-build. Instead of replacing, it is common to add prefix and suffix to the resource strings (the values in properties file) and test the application for errors.

Unfortunately, this will only give you the subset of hardcoded string defects, as there is almost no way to test all the possible execution paths. And of course it is easy to omit the contents of alt and title attributes during testing - you might have hard times noticing the problem.

Honestly, there is no easy method to spot i18n errors in the code. In order to do that, you will probably need to run some commercial tool like Globylizer, or develop your own. If you focus only on hardcoded strings (which are frankly only part of the problem), you may hack some regular expression to find the text between opening and closing tag and file a defect if it is not anything like `<s:text>` or whatever you use for translations.